# Text input does not change slider value on first attempt

Tags: javascript, slider

I am making a password generator with a text input and slider value that are tied together, however when I type in a value the first time it will not update. When I try again it works, as well as working subsequent times. The slider value always updates. I don't know what is wrong with the code to make it perform like this though, still fairly new to JS.

//html

```
<div class="slider">
    <input type="text" id="slider-input" value="" onchange="setSlider(this)">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="64" value="1" id="slider" oninput="myFunction(this)">
</div>
```

//JS

```
const sliderInput = document.getElementById("slider-input");
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");

let passLength = "";
function myFunction() {
    slider.oninput = function() {
    sliderInput.value = this.value;
    passLength = this.value;
    }
}

function setSlider() {
    sliderInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    slider.value = this.value; 
    passLength = this.value;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `setSlider` function. On the first invocation you are adding the event listener. Therefore, it is only after that initial call that we see the intended behavior.

Rather than calling `addEventListener` on each change, you can remove it all together:

```
function setSlider({value}) {
  slider.value = value; 
  passLength = value;
}
```

[repl](https://replit.com/@JamesonJackson/SatisfiedInternationalArchive#index.html)